# Indecipherable VMware/Vagrant error message

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vagrant, vmware-fusion

My company uses Vagrant within VMware for development.  Everyone else (10+ people) has the setup running smoothly, but I've run into a confounding problem that none of us can solve.

After adding a vagrant box with `vagrant box add sgvm http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64_vmware.box` I try to start vagrant with `vagrant up seatgeek --provider=vmware_fusion`.  This throws this error:

```
An error occurred while executing `vmrun`, a utility for controlling
VMware machines. The command and output are below:

Command: ["start", "/Users/jack/Sites/sg/seatgeek-vm/.vagrant/machines/seatgeek/vmware_fusion/f2e2bebf-e1cb-4bc1-862b-9cb957e13065/precise64.vmx", "nogui", {:notify=>[:stdout, :stderr]}]

Stdout: 2014-02-06T09:20:29.661| ServiceImpl_Opener: PID 20276
Error: The operation was canceled

Stderr:
```

I got in touch with VMware support.  They said that they can't support it, but they would confirm that `vmrun` was working properly.  They asked me to run `vmrun -T fusion start` and verified that the output was expected.  Based on this, they said it was a Vagrant problem.  I have tried to contact Vagrant support but they have been non-responsive.

Anyone have any idea what might cause this?  Or ideas about other things I should investigate?

Comment: When you say you tried to contact vagrant support did you log an issue on github. If not I would log an issue with as much info as possible like vagrant version, host operating system version etc. You could also link it to this post.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I just [created an issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2944).

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Opened issue #3273 on the vagrant GitHub.

Answer (score 4):

I saw this when I tried to dial the memory on my vm too high.  After a certain limit, fusion doesn't even try.  See the `memsize` line of my block below.

```
config.vm.provider 'vmware_fusion' do |provider, override|
  # provider.gui = true
  override.vm.box_url = 'http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64_vmware.box'
  provider.vmx['memsize'] = '3072'  # VMware refuses to start for anything larger
  provider.vmx['numvcpus'] = '1'    # http://superuser.com/q/505711/96477
end
```

Comment: This happened to me after upgrading VMWare Workstation - turns out it was blocked on waiting for me to enter the new license key :)
enabling the gui opened VMWare Workstation and the prompt

Comment: I had a similar failure with an even more useless error message when the underlying problem was that Hyper-V was activated. On my oldold Windows LTSC, Hyper-V is incompatible with VMware Workstation and must be turned off. When I did, Vagrant worked.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible source of this error is that the vagrant box may have the wrong architecture. I had unintentionally downloaded an x86 box on my M2 mac, which gave this error. When I switched to using an arm64 box, the VM started correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO2wr.png)

Enabled my gui and found out that the error was coming due to the VMWare version being incompatible with Mac M1.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to change the vm.box name, currently it downloaded the x86 but you need something like arm64. Also after change this, you need to delete the .vagrant directory and then run vagrant up. It should work.